# Count number of business days between given two dates grouped by month in a table

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lubridate

I have a dataframe in R which contains three columns: employee_number, start_date and end_date.

A simple example of the dataframe (there are hundreds of rows in the real data) is:

```
df <- data.frame(
  employee_number = c(1001, 1002, 1003),
  start_date = as.Date(c('2023-01-15', '2023-02-10', '2023-03-05')),
  end_date = as.Date(c('2023-03-10', '2023-04-20', '2023-06-15'))
)
```

I need to produce another dataframe which retains employee_number as the first column, and then introduces a new column for each month which contains a period between all of the start_date and end_dates. The values in the table should count the number of business or working days (excluding weekends and a pre-defined list of bank holidays) which fall in that particular column's month and lie between the start_date and end_date for that employee.

For the simple example dataset above with three employees, the resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
df_result <- data.frame(
  employee_number = c(1001, 1002, 1003),
  2023-01 = c(12, 0, 0),
  2023-02 = c(20, 13, 0),
  2023-03 = c(8, 23, 20),
  2023-04 = c(0, 12, 18),
  2023-05 = c(0, 0, 20),
  2023-06 = c(0, 0, 11)
)
```

I have been able to produce a tibble for an individual row of the data using the below code, but I need some help into how I can use a function or loop to repeat this for every row in the original dataset and output it all into one dataframe of the prespecified above format and not as singular individual tibbles per employee number. Is anyone able to help please?

Code for one individual row that needs scaling up:

```
start_date <- "2023-01-15"
end_date <- "2023-03-10"

#create a data.frame with all days from start date to end date
df <- data.frame( dates = seq( as.Date(start_date), as.Date(end_date), by = "days"))

#create the vector with bank holidays
holidays <- as.Date(c("2023-01-02", "2023-04-07", "2023-04-10", "2023-05-01", "2023-05-08", "2023-05-29", "2023-08-28"))

df %>% 
  #filter out all days that are Sundays (wday == 1), or Saturdays (wday == 7), or within the vector of bank holidays
  filter(!lubridate::wday(dates) %in% c(1,7) & !dates %in% holidays) %>%
  #create period to summarise by (here: year-month)
  mutate(period = paste(lubridate::year(dates), formatC(lubridate::month(dates), width = 2, format = "d", flag = "0"), sep = "-") ) %>%
  # group by period and summarise
  group_by(period) %>%
  summarise(working_days = n())
```

Comment: How exactly do you define months? Is it when the "month" digit changes? Is it always a multiple of 30? Or does it change based on days in the month (including leap years)? I tend to avoid count months, it introduces many corner-cases where interpretation is contextual and/or subjective.

Comment: @r2evans Months defined as the actual calendar months, when the month digit changes

Comment: Okay, so from `"2023-01-31"` to `"2023-02-01"` should be `1`, and from `"2023-01-01"` to `"2023-02-28"` should also be `1`, right?